# Vertically align two boxes based on their top borders, not on baseline

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

I have two boxes which to shows text to the left and right of a document.

```
\begin{minipage}[t][1in][t]{2in}
{\Huge First line box 1}\\
{\footnotesize Second line box 1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][1in][t]{2in}
    \begin{flushright}
{\footnotesize
First line box 2\\
Second line box 2
}
\end{minipage}
```

These boxes align based on the baseline, however it looks ugly because of the huge text of box 1. I know I can raise box 2 a bit with `\raisebox` so that they are aligned based on top border of box 1, but it's kind of hacky. Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t][1in][t]{2in}\vspace{0pt}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\Huge First line box 1\\
\footnotesize Second line box 1
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][1in][t]{2in}\vspace{0pt}
\footnotesize\raggedleft
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
First line box 2\\
Second line box 2 \par
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]